# Convert WP Password to SMF Password

Tags: hash, passwords, smf

I need to import users from Wordpress to SMF.
I have access to database, we all passwords hashes from smf and WP, but I cant figure it out how to convert them to be albe to clone account with those 2 engines.
Any clue how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to.  Passwords are hashed in wordpress and SMF and cannot be retrieved.

The best thing to do is just store the password they have now and then send an email out to all people saying that to log in, they'll have to change their password.  They won't be able to get in until that's done.